# Specifying independence of a variable in a function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction, differentials

I am dealing with a function of a finite number of variables and among
the operations I wish to do is to differentiate it repeatedly with
respect with any of the variables.

Now this function happens to be
defined in terms of an unknown function, which only depends on a
proper subset of the variables.  I would like to tell this to
Mathematica; i.e., for the purposes of differentiation, the unknown
function is independent of a number of the variables.

The following minimal example shows what I am trying to do (and
failing).  Here `f` is supposed to be a function of only `y`, whereas `g` is defined in terms of `f` and is a function of both `x` and `y`.

```
g = x f + y 
(* f x + y *)

f /: D[f, x, NonConstants -> {f}] := 0

D[g, x, NonConstants -> {f}]
(* f *)

D[g, x, y, NonConstants -> {f}]
(* D[f, y, NonConstants -> {f}] *)

D[g, y, x, NonConstants -> {f}]
(* D[f, y, NonConstants -> {f}] + x D[f, x, y, NonConstants  -> {f}] *)
```

I can assume that f is infinitely continuously differentiable, whence
mixed partials commute and hence the second term should be absent.
I could try to substitute `In[2]` by a more comprehensive rule which tests whether
the variables on which `f` does not depend appear in `v` where `v` is
defined by `D[f,v__, NonConstants->{f}]`.  However I wonder whether
there is perhaps a simpler way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not define the expressions in such a way that their dependence on the independent variables is explicit:

```
ClearAll[f, g, x, y]

g[x_, y_] = x f[y] + y

(* ==> y + x f[y] *)

D[g[x, y], y, x]

(* ==> Derivative[1][f][y] *)

D[g[x, y], x, y]

(* ==> Derivative[1][f][y] *)
```

The mixed derivatives now agree.

Comment: Thanks!  That’s eminently reasonable… I should have tried that before asking the question.